# tsearch function does not maintain struct pointer within struct. Loss of information issue

Tags: c, struct, binary-tree

I am using a tree in C to keep track of an undefined and varying number of input fields. I have a struct with a set number of fields as follows:

```
struct mystruct {
    int id, mpid;
    char *name;
    struct myotherstruct *myostr;
};
```

I have a pointer instance of this type ( mystruct ) which I allocate memory for, then I fill these struct values in with input I've read from a file. I then use the tsearch function from search.h to add my mystruct object to the mystruct tree.  The problem I am having, is that if I use the tfind function to retrieve a mystruct pointer from the tree, the mystruct memory that is returned has no recollection of the myotherstruct pointer data I allocated and pointed to when creating the value prior to adding to the tree.

The general sequence is as follows:

```
struct mystruct {
    int id, mpid;
    char *name;
    struct myotherstruct *myostr;
};

struct myotherstruct {
    int spid;
};

// allocate memory to temporary mystruct pointer
// add mpid field to mystruct pointer ( used in comparison function )

if( // tfind  == NULL )
{
    // set id value
    // allocate char memory and strncpy correct value in
    // allocate myotherstruct memory and assign all values
    // tsearch for this newly created mystruct memory chunk so that it is added to tree
}
else
{
    // fails here when attempting to access the data returned by mytfind
}

...
```

Using gdb, the program very clearly enters the if loop the first time ( since the tree is empty ) and creates a valid and full mystruct pointer with proper memory allocation. When tsearch returns it's output, the memory location is different from that of the mystruct pointer I filled in and then I am incapable of doing prints for mystruct->myotherstruct variables such as spid. The exact output I get when attempting to print in gdb is : Cannot access memory at address 0x----- where the -'s are various locations in memory that I apparently cannot access.

I suspect that there may be a problem with my comparison function since I am only comparing mystruct mpid fields to determine whether a tree node exists yet for a mystruct object, but my inexperience with both C and tsearch/tfind functionality are showing a bit here. Hopefully someone with more experience is able to help me since the examples provided on various tsearch.h webpages don't handle very sophisticated examples. Thanks in advance for the help!

PS: the code must remain in C, so language swapping doesn't suffice :(

EDIT:

here is my compare function:

```
int distcmp(const void *a, const void *b){
   return ((int)((struct mystruct *)a)->mpid) != (int)(((struct mystruct *)b)->mpid);
}
```

Also, I use tfind initially because I want to know whether a particular value exists in the tree yet. If it does not exist ( it returns NULL ) then it enters the if loop and fills in the new mystruct object and adds it to the tree ( using tsearch ). If it already exists, a pointer to that object comes out of tfind which I assign to a mystruct pointer and use in the else portion of the code. Hopefully this helps. Thanks again.

SOLVED:

Just to update, the issue is that the returned pointer from tsearch and tfind is not of the type mystruct. It is a pointer to the memory location of the mystruct value that matched my search. In this case, the issue would be resolved by accessing the returned pointer with a * and passing that value to a mystruct pointer. Thanks to those who commented.

Comment: you'll need to add more details/code. what is the function signature for the `tsearch` function? How do you use it? what is `tfind` in your pseudocode?

Comment: The functions [`tsearch()`, `tfind()`, `tdelete()` and `twalk()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tsearch.html) are defined in the standard POSIX header [`<search.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/search.h.html#tag_13_40), which was also a part of the SVID.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Even though you don't need to describe the tree functions, you do need to show your compare function, and be more explicit about how you're calling the `tsearch()` and `tfind()` functions (and explain why you don't simply call `tsearch()`).  You should look at the example code on the POSIX page; it should help you.